# Looking for details on this 'creation': Monod with his Ego-Puppet

Tags: object-identification

Graphic artist Wayne Barlowe published a book *Barlowe's Guide to Fantasy*, wherein he depicts various creatures and characters from a wide range of fantasy works by different writers including Clive Barker, Michael Moorcock, Robert Howard and others.

At the back of this collection are a group of sketches, including one of a bizarre-looking creature labeled a 'Monod', holding something called an 'Ego puppet'.

I could not find another depiction or mention of this 'Monod' anywhere else in the book and searches for it online have gotten me nowhere- has anyone on this site seen mention of it and if so, where?

[image]

Comment: Can you include a picture, in case we've seen it, or something like, under a different name?

Comment: @DavidW I was looking at a picture of it as you posted your comment. It's certainly bizarre.

Comment: The intro to the sketches say that they are early studies for the book and "for his upcoming project called *Pilgrimage to Hell*". Presumably it's for the latter.

Comment: It also mentioned in the The Alien Life of Wayne Barlowe: https://morpheusgallery.com/Other%20Fine%20Artists/item.php?work=692 https://www.amazon.com/Alien-Life-Wayne-Barlowe/dp/188339810X

Comment: Wayne Barlowe has a history of putting sketches at the end of his early books for characters he intended to make other books around, but never completed.  For example, here is one I spent many years hoping for: https://www.ebay.com/itm/313576064243. You can also see one of his sketches for Thype eventually show up as a character in the Hell Boy 2 movie.